# css background zoom with fade in effect

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, css-transitions

Using the following zoom in effect from here https://codepen.io/dragoeco/pen/ibrzK

need some assistance with getting a background image fade in with zoom effect on hover like the one here http://fantasy.co/work keeping the foreground logo same.

```css
.image-box{
  width:300px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.image {
 width:300px;
  height:200px;
 background: url("http://lorempixel.com/300/200");
 background-position:center;
 transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
} 
.image:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.5);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
  -o-transform: scale(1.5);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.5); /* IE 9 */
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=1.5, M12=0, M21=0, M22=1.5, SizingMethod='auto expand')"; /* IE8 */
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=1.5, M12=0, M21=0, M22=1.5, SizingMethod='auto expand'); /* IE6 and 7 */ 
}
```

```html
<div class="image-box">
  <div class="image">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the hover from `image` to the `image-box`, placed a label inside the `image-box` and added the following css:

```
.image-box, .image {
  position: relative;
}
.image:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
}
.label {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bolder;
}
.image-box:hover .image:after {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Check this out and let me know your feedback. Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Increased the transition time on `image` too. :)

```css
.image-box {
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.image {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: url("http://lorempixel.com/300/200");
  background-position: center;
  transition: all 10s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 10s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 10s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 10s ease;
  -o-transition: all 10s ease;
}
.image-box:hover .image {
  transform: scale(1.5);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.5);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
  -o-transform: scale(1.5);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.5);
  /* IE 9 */
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=1.5, M12=0, M21=0, M22=1.5, SizingMethod='auto expand')";
  /* IE8 */
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=1.5, M12=0, M21=0, M22=1.5, SizingMethod='auto expand');
  /* IE6 and 7 */
}

.image-box, .image {
  position: relative;
}
.image:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
}
.label {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bolder;
}
.image-box:hover .image:after {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-box">
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="label">LABEL</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This helped a lot and is correct ! thanks a bunch ! @kukkuz

Answer (score 0):

```css
.image-box{
  width:300px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.image {
 width:300px;
  height:200px;
 background: url("http://lorempixel.com/300/200");
 background-position:center;
 transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  position: relative;
} 

.image:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.5);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
  -o-transform: scale(1.5);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.5); /* IE 9 */
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=1.5, M12=0, M21=0, M22=1.5, SizingMethod='auto expand')"; /* IE8 */
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=1.5, M12=0, M21=0, M22=1.5, SizingMethod='auto expand'); /* IE6 and 7 */ 
} 

.image:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
  transition: background-color 1s ease;
}

.image:hover:after {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0 ,0 , 0.4);
}
```

```html
<div class="image-box">
  <div class="image">
  </div>
</div>
```

I m not sure if this is what you are looking for but get a try and if it's not ill redo my code;

First of all add a position relative to your .image class

```
.image {position: relative;}
```

then add this:

```
.image:after {
      content: '';
      display: block;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
      transition: background-color 1s ease;
    }

    .image:hover:after {
      background-color: rgba(255, 0 ,0 , 0.4);
    }
```

Comment: thanks ShadowFoOm , well im trying to get the reverse of this where the image in the background and fades in and zooms. and the foreground has text.  which stays constant . exactly like the divs in this fantasy.co/work link

Comment: i chose to use the zooming effect but i can go with something else thats works.

Comment: well to reverse the fade efect u just have to play with the opacity of the `background-color: rgba` but if you need to add text too, then you 'll have to do as kukkuz says. that's one way you can do it.